# Issue with Beautifulsoup .find(text=true)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
cells = row.find_all('td')
if len(cells)==10: #Only extract table body not heading
    A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
    B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
    C.append(cells[2].find('div').get('title'))
    D.append(cells[3].find('a', href=True).get_text())
    E.append(cells[4].find('a', href=True).get_text())
    if cells[5].find(text=True) is None or cells[5].find('a', href=True) is None:
        F.append(cells[5].find(text=True))
    else:
        Output = '-'.join([item.get_text() for item in cells[5].find_all('a')])
        F.append(Output)
    if  cells[6].find(text=True) is None or cells[6].find('a', href=True) is None:
        G.append(cells[6].find(text=True))
    else: 
        G.append(cells[6].find('a', href=True).get_text())
    if cells[7].find(text=True) is None or cells[7].find('a', href=True) is None:
        H.append(cells[7].find(text=True))
    else: 
        H.append(cells[7].find('a', href=True).get_text())          
    I.append(cells[8].find('span').get_text())
    J.append(cells[9].find(Title=True))
```

The problem is that at cells 5,6 and 7 the desired output is sometimes inside a ahref tag and sometimes inside a td tag. The code works but the List F f.e. looks something like this:

```
0          
T-001
1        
TD-U1B
2       BMA-D2-USA
3      BMU-D3-USA 
4
```

Position 2 and 3 are correct. These are the outputs from:

```
else:

     Output = '-'.join([item.get_text() for item in cells[5].find_all('a')])

     F.append(Output)
```

Position 0 and 1 are incorrect. These are the outputs from:

```
F.append(cells[5].find(text=True))
```

Comment: Hey @nule, welcome to SO, your code is a little cryptic, if you post a sample of your data and desired output that will help people better understand and help. [mcve]

Comment: without knowing your html it hard to fix